# How to enable/disable tool tips with code

Tags: c#, tooltip

How to enable/disable tooltips with code.
I am able to enable tooltips for a button with code on form load, but cannot turn tooltips off with code for a checkbox.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the ToolTip and associate with the Form container.
    ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();

    // Set up the ToolTip text for a Button.
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.btnRunExtApp, "Run the external application");
}
```

Works perfectly.

I am now trying to make a user option to turn on/off the tooltip with a checkbox.

```
private void ChkEnableTips_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();

    if (ChkEnableTips.Checked == true)
    {
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.btnRunExtApp, "Run the external application");
    }
    if (ChkEnableTips.Checked == false)
    {               
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.btnRunExtApp, null);
    }
}
```

Maybe it is because I am declaring toolTip1 again?
I tried to change it to toolTip2 but this did not work either.
But if I do not declare it at all in ChkEnableTips_CheckedChanged then I get an error (The name 'toolTip1' does not exist in the current context).

Comment: I feel like when I've done this in the past I've created the `ToolTip` control through the designer, so it exists at the class scope. That way I reuse the same one each time (not that you explicitly need the designer at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is because you declare it again. Write to the top of your class a global variable.

```
ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
```

Then events (also the constructor) can use it:

```
private void ChkEnableTips_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ChkEnableTips.Checked == true)
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.btnRunExtApp, "Run the external application");
    if (ChkEnableTips.Checked == false)
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.btnRunExtApp, null);
}
```

Do not set `toolTip1` in `Load` event, go to the designer view instead and set your checkbox to be ticked by default. This will raise the event anyway and the handler above does the job for you. Also this way you avoid a 2nd call to `SetToolTip()`.

(Btw, some info for your future design when you want init in `constructor` - instead of `Load` -: the field initialization happens before the lines in the constructor.)

**Edit:**

Maybe there is a component in the *Toolbox* called ToolTip. You can drag and drop. It does not change anything! just moves this line:

```
ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
```

To the *designer.cs*

Comment: Thanks this is some considerable improvement. I removed all the load code for the toolTip1 and added the line as a global variable. When I start the app tooltips are not showing, but they are if I uncheck and then check the check box. I then tried to add the tooltip toolbox component but this got added as toolTip2. So i deleted the component, deleted the new global variable and added a toolTip component again. This time it added as toolTip1. I cannot find the line ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip(); in the designer cs. But it is still working if I first uncheck, then check the tooltip check box.

Comment: Is there any way I can make tooltips be on when the app loads. Thanks for your time. Its appreciated.

Comment: Ok if I add the same tooltip text in the designer it works well. Just have to duplicate it exactly same text in both designer and my if statements code for the checkbox.

Comment: Try to debug your code. Put a breakpoint in the CheckedChange event. It seems not fired when the form is created/loaded. Is this because you are not subscribing to this event from the designer but from your code at some other place?

Comment: To be honest a lot of what you are saying is going over my head. I am new to both C# and Visual Studio. What little coding I have done in the past has been html and some JavaScript using notepad++. I am trying to learn though. So far, I have the dragged toolTip1 from the Toolbox to the form. For the button I have enabled the tooltip1 text in designer. Then I have my if statement for the change event on the checkbox. I am not aware of any other place i have added the code (I just checked and cannot find it anywhere else, except for what has been added automatically).

Comment: So in your designer, if you select *ChkEnableTips* and select the *events* pictogram, you see *ChkEnableTips_CheckedChanged* written, right? :)

Comment: Not sure what that means? I created a new test project and it works exactly the same. So I added the same code from the checkbox to the form load code and it is working as it should. I have now removed the toolTips1 text from the button in designer. I have copied the code for the if statements for the checkbox to the form load event ans it is working. Repeated this in my main project and this is now working too. Everything works as intended now. I am happy. Thanks very much for your help.